# First Derivative of Cubic Spline on SAS

Tags: sas

How to take first derivative of cubic spline on sas

I am stuck at the below:

```
proc Transreg data=A;
  model identity(y)=spline (x/ nknots=4);
Run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ODS OUTPUT SPLINECOEF=<dataset>` to capture the spline coefficients.